# Line numering with multicolumn mode

Tags: multicol, linenumber

Here I faced challenge for fixing line number style as like the attached image could any one help how to fix this.

Note:
Required style as indicated in green color

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\section{Overview}
Numerous videos 
and interactivities are embedded just 
where you need them, at the point of 

\subsection{Links with our times}
When a new suburb is established today, roads and footpaths are built,
services such as water and electricity are connected, and underground 
pipes are installed to take away sewage and 
stormwater. All these facilities are 
usually in place before any homes are built, 
and even the construction of the 
houses is governed by strict building regulations. 
The situation was very 
different two hundred years ago.

\begin{multicols}{2}
As we learned in topic 2, the population increased dramatically in 
Britain during the Industrial Revolution. Changes in agricultural 
practices,  as well as job opportunities in the 
newly established factories, brought 
large numbers of people into rapidly growing towns and cities. This 
influx of people was not matched by the provision 
of the types of server 

As we learned in topic 2, the population increased dramatically in 
Britain during the Industrial Revolution. Changes in agricultural    
practices, as well as job opportunities in the newly established 
factories, brought large numbers of people into rapidly 
growing towns and cities. This 
influx of people was not matched by the provision 
of the types of server 
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you asking for line numbers in this format only in the left column, or do you want them in both columns?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? This solution assumes you only want line numbers in the left column. If you want them in all columns, delete the `docolaction` macro that wraps the `\underline` macro.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\usepackage{lineno}

\setlength{\columnsep}{36pt} % to make room
\setlength{\linenumberwidth}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\linenumberfont}{\normalsize}%
\renewcommand{\LineNumber}{%
    \docolaction{%
    \underline{\makebox[\linenumberwidth][r]{\ifnum\thelinenumber=1 1\else \themodulolinenumber\fi}}%
    }{}{}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Overview}
Numerous videos
and interactivities are embedded just 
where you need them, at the point of 

\subsection{Links with our times}
When a new suburb is established today, roads and footpaths are built,
services such as water and electricity are connected, and underground 
pipes are installed to take away sewage and 
stormwater. All these facilities are 
usually in place before any homes are built, 
and even the construction of the 
houses is governed by strict building regulations. 
The situation was very 
different two hundred years ago.

\begin{multicols}{2}
\linenumbers%
As we learned in topic 2, the population increased dramatically in 
Britain during the Industrial Revolution. Changes in agricultural 
practices,  as well as job opportunities in the 
newly established factories, brought 
large numbers of people into rapidly growing towns and cities. This 
influx of people was not matched by the provision 
of the types of server 

As we learned in topic 2, the population increased dramatically in 
Britain during the Industrial Revolution. Changes in agricultural    
practices, as well as job opportunities in the newly established 
factories, brought large numbers of people into rapidly 
growing towns and cities. This 
influx of people was not matched by the provision 
of the types of server 
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image: underlined line numbers with multicol]

Comment: Thank you so much! Karl. It does really match and works what I required.

Comment: If it solves your problem, don't forget to accept the solution.