# Line numbers required in multi column text

Tags: multicol, line-numbering

[image]Here I faced challenge for fixing line number style as like the attached image could any one help how to fix this.

Note: Required style as indicated in green color

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multicols}enter image description here

\begin{document}

\section{Overview}

Numerous videos \textbf{xxx} $\textbf{Xx}\quad {\boldsymbol{Xx}}$ and interactivities are embedded just where you need them, at the point of learning, in your learnON title at www.jacplus.com.au. They will help you to learn the content and concepts covered in this topic. SOURCE 1 The rapid growth of towns during the Industrial Revolution resulted in most workers and their families living in slum conditions.

\subsection{Links with our times}

When a new suburb is established today, roads and footpaths are built, services such as water and electricity are connected, and underground pipes are installed to take away sewage and stormwater. All these facilities are usually in place before any homes are built, and even the construction of the houses is governed by strict building regulations. The situation was very different two hundred years ago.

\begin{multicols}{2}

As we learned in topic 2, the population increased dramatically in Britain during the Industrial Revolution. Changes in agricultural practices, as well as job opportunities in the newly established factories, brought large numbers of people into rapidly growing towns and cities. This influx of people was not matched by the provision of the types of server

As we learned in topic 2, the population increased dramatically in Britain during the Industrial Revolution. Changes in agricultural practices, as well as job opportunities in the newly established factories, brought large numbers of people into rapidly growing towns and cities. This influx of people was not matched by the provision of the types of server

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451398/line-numering-with-multicolumn-mode?

Comment: Or [this here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451394/121799)? Wouldn't it be better if you asked one clear question instead of several vague very similar ones?